# Alternate link in href attribute

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, href

I would like to create a download button in HTML such that if it is clicked, a file will be download from an URL. However, if the URL is not present (it returns a 404 error), it will try to download the file from an alternate link. If the alternate link also fails, do nothing.

Presently, I am using `href` attribute of `a` tag to create download link.
How to do the above mentioned process with the help of `href` attribute?
If it is not possible with `href` then what is the procedure to create such a button?

**UPDATE:**

```
<a href="downloadlink.com/somefile.exe">Download File</a>
```

Comment: It's not possible in HTML without the help of either server-side or client-side scripting.

Comment: Could you show the actual code you are using?

Comment: @jsve what for? It is pretty obvious what "code" the OP is using: a html anchor tag.

Comment: Yes, you are right @arkascha

Comment: @jsve I am use a html anchor tag
<a href="http://dowloadlink.com/somefile.exe">Download File</a>

Comment: lol, I love such links in the MS-Windows world: downloading some executable. Next question will be if it is possible to execute that without user interaction to make it more convenient. Apart from that: the answer has been given, it is final: this is only possible using scripting.

Comment: @arkascha No, I was not going to ask that. It is just going to be an installer file of one of my applications and it need not be auto-executed.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Nothing. It is just a comment. sorry for being chatty.

Comment: @arkascha Well, yes I understand that is the unfortunate answer. Could you please tell me how to do it via server/client side scripting ... which ever is easier. I intend to provide an alternative download url in case the primary url fails in order to provide better user experience.
At present, only one link is being used : http://www.pratanumandal.tk/fileguard.html

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I never claimed that is not possible in other systems. But as you said: this is off-topic :-)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro He can check the links to my applications on my website and scan them for viruses all he wants. Could you please tell me how to create such a download link in order to provide better downloading feature? Please refer to my last comment.

Comment: @PratanuMandal you can use AJAX and/or a link to a back-end file that will download the right content

Comment: @PratanuMandal I have no intention to do so, no. You got me wrong. I am not concerned about the content you want to offer for downloading. It was a general remark about that general problem on that platform. It was off-topic, indeed. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro please post some sample code or provide a link that can act as a starting point. I have been Googling in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fiddler for you with a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/zbb7j2pq/1/

HTML:

```
<a id="button" href="" 
    data-primary-target="http://www1.some-server.example/file"
    data-secondary-target="http://www2.some-server.example/file"
    data-ternary-target="http://www2.some-server.example/file">
    Download
</a>
```

Script (using the jQuery library in this case for convenience):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var targets = [
            $(e.target).data('primary-target'),
            $(e.target).data('secondary-target'),
            $(e.target).data('ternary-target')
        ];
        $(targets).each(function(key, target){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'HEAD',
                url: target,
                success: function() {
                    window.location = target;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you run that code in the fiddler, then you can see the head requests to the targets inside the network tab of your browsers development console. The actual download does not start due to cross  domain issues. That is a separate question, though.

The code allows you to iterate through specified alternatives and execute a routine for each. Inside that routine you could then make a head request and check if it is valid and usable. If so: change the windows location object to it and the download will start. If not just skip to the next alternative.

This should point you into the right direction. But you will have to dig into JavaScript programming a little for this.

Comment: Thank you! I shall try to integrate it into my download button.

Comment: I updated the answer once more to implement the actual network request strategy.